# The @error not showing the Errors in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

In Blade, not showing the single `@error` but in `@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)` showing all errors.
this is the validation

```
public function updateAthlete(){
        $pass = Hash::make($this->password);
        $info = Athlete::find($this->athlete_id);
    if($this->profile_photo_path){
        File::delete('storage/' . $this->filePath);
        $this->filePath = $this->profile_photo_path->store('AthletesProfile', 'public');
    }

    $this->validate([
        'name'               =>'required|max:70|min:3',
        'name_fa'            =>'required|max:70|min:3',
        'name_pa'            =>'required|max:70|min:3',
    ]);
    
    $info->update([
        'name'               => $this->name,
        'name_fa'            => $this->name_fa,
        'name_pa'            => $this->name_pa,
   ]);

   session()->flash('updated', 'Post successfully updated.');

}
```

and this is the form

```
<div class="form-group form-group-default">
    <label>Name in Farsi</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" dir="RTL" wire:model="name_fa">
  @error('name_fa') <span class="error" style="color:red">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
</div>
```

it didn't show any error in the console or it's not about styling

Comment: This will work `@if ($errors->has('name_fa')) <span class="error" style="color:red">{{ $errors->first('name_fa') }}</span> @endif`

Comment: that didn't work also

Comment: You need to pass a `Request` object to the `validate` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use validate function like this.

You need to pass a Request instance to make it work :

```
public function updateAthlete(Request $request) 
{
    // .....

    $request->validate([
        'name'               =>'required|max:70|min:3',
        'name_fa'            =>'required|max:70|min:3',
        'name_pa'            =>'required|max:70|min:3',
    ]);

    // or :

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'               =>'required|max:70|min:3',
        'name_fa'            =>'required|max:70|min:3',
        'name_pa'            =>'required|max:70|min:3',
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is by creating a Form Request Validation by `php artisan make:request UpdateAthleteRequest`, the file will be in `app\Http\Requests` folder and add your rules to the rules() method.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'               =>'required|max:70|min:3',
        'name_fa'            =>'required|max:70|min:3',
        'name_pa'            =>'required|max:70|min:3',
    ];
}
```

In your controller, use the file and:

```
public function updateAthlete(UpdateAthleteRequest $request){
$pass = Hash::make($this->password);
        $info = Athlete::find($this->athlete_id);
    if($this->profile_photo_path){
        File::delete('storage/' . $this->filePath);
        $this->filePath = $this->profile_photo_path->store('AthletesProfile', 'public');
    }
    
    $info->update($request->validated());

   session()->flash('updated', 'Post successfully updated.');
}
```

You have to redirect to a viewfile when done. As it stands now, your visitor will see an empty page after updating the data.

Comment: Question @user13708077 are you using livewire? This is not clear from the code you provided. I just noticed the tag `laravel-livewire`.... My suggestion is designed for a non-livewire environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
`$data = array_merge($data, [
    'name'               => $this->name,
    'name_fa'            => $this->name_fa,
    'name_pa'            => $this->name_pa,
```

]);`

```
`$validateData = array_merge($validateData, [
    'name'               =>'required|max:70|min:3',
    'name_fa'            =>'required|max:70|min:3',
    'name_pa'            =>'required|max:70|min:3',
]);`

`$validation = Validator::make($data, $validateData)->validate();`

`$info->update($validation);`

`session()->flash('updated', 'Post successfully updated.');`
```